# Is it possible to add a proxy in front of an auth provider for OIDC or OpenAuth2.0?

Tags: scala, oauth-2.0, playframework, openid-connect, okta

I have the below specs:

- (A) 3rd Party Messageboard (Can only user OAuth2.0 or OIDC)
- (B) Auth Source (Okta)
- (C) A PlayFramework front end with a login page (using B as the source)

With the requirements that users should be able to go to A and choose to login from C. The problem is that C is not an auth server, it just uses one (B). I can set the message board to point to Okta, but Okta only allows a custom login page (redirect) via SAML. If I use OIDC or OAuth then it expects users to login to Okta directly* and **. So, my current workaround thought is to point A directly to C which already uses B behind the scenes. The problem is that C is not an OIDC or OAuth server. Is there some easy way to have my Playframework code bubble up the Okta configurations so that A could talk to C directly? I'm guessing it would somehow break security protocols and is not possible...but I had to ask. Any thoughts on this possibility?

*Even if I could skin the Okta login to look like ours, we have obfuscated the user login such that their Okta email != the websites email - so it would not succeed.

**I am waiting for Okta support to see if there is a way to redirect to my code (C) as I can with SAML, but all signs point to no.

Comment: I found this - so I guess I need to implement this - https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#_2-okta-as-the-identity-platform-for-your-app-or-api ?

Comment: Or not...because the messageboard service is the one creating the redirect_uri back to itself, which is possibly the key?